# TVD property of slope limiter method

Tags: numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the scalar conservation law $u_t+f(u)_x=0,$ whose monotone conservative and consistent first order numerical scheme is given by
\begin{equation}\label{1}u_i^{n+1}=u_i^n-\lambda\left(F(u_i^n,u_{i+1}^n)-F(u_{i-1}^n,u_{i}^n) \right)
\end{equation}

Suppose we modify the above scheme by $$u_i^{n+1}=u_i^n-\lambda\left[F\left(u_{i+\frac{1}{2}}^{L,n},u_{i+\frac{1}{2}}^{R,n}\right)-F\left(u_{i-\frac{1}{2}}^{L,n},u_{i-\frac{1}{2}}^{R,n}\right) \right]$$
where $u_{i+\frac{1}{2}}^{L,n},u_{i+\frac{1}{2}}^{R,n}$ are the left and right limits at the point $x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}$ of the piecewise linear approximations of the piecewise constant functions given by $$v(x)=\sum\limits_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}\displaystyle{\chi_{C_i}u_i^n},$$ with slopes $p_i$ in interval $C_i.$

Suppose, $p_i, i\in \mathbb{Z}$  are chosen so that total variation of the piecewiese linear approximation is same as the total variation of the piecewise constant function (For example minmod limiter), **then how to show that second order reconstruction as explained above is also TVD?.**

Comment: The same way as you would prove the TVD property for any scheme, I suppose.

Comment: @EditPiAf generally tvd properties are proved for monotone scheme. This is scheme is not monotone..can u please mention which way u are reffering to..

Comment: I think your formulation of the piecewise linear functions should be something like $\chi_{C_i} \big( u_i^n + p_i( x - x_i) \big)$.

Comment: I do not understand why the second version should not be monotone if the first one is.
For monotonicity of locally Lipschitz cont. two-point fluxes you have monotonicity iff $\partial_a F(a,b) \geq 0$ and $\partial_b F(a,b) \leq 0$. If that holds for the first version, it should hold for the second version as well.